# Run Vagrant inside Docker container

Tags: docker, vagrant

I am looking for a way to run vagrant inside docker container. I tried using Ubuntu base container but had faced some issues while doing vagrant up, it failed.

```
root@991baf290ddc:/srv# vagrant up
VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run VBoxManage --version to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

```
root@991baf290ddc:/srv# VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist. Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate headers, most likely linux-headers-.
     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.0.40_Ubuntur115130
```

I tried installing `virtualbox-dkms` package but no help.

```
Deleting module version: 5.0.40 completely from the DKMS tree.
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-5.0.40 DKMS files...
dpkg: warning: version '*-*' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
dpkg: warning: version '3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64' has bad syntax: invalid character in revision number
It is likely that 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 belongs to a chroot's host
Building only for *
Building initial module for *
: using /lib/modules/4.4.0-83-generic/build/.config
(I hope this is the correct config for this kernel)
Done.
```

```
Error! The directory /lib/modules/* doesn't exist.
You cannot install a module onto a non-existant kernel.
The command '/bin/sh -c dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms' returned a non-zero code: 6
[root@test-docker vagrant-in-docker]#
```

Comment: did you install `linux-headers-generic` ?

Comment: Yes but no help

Comment: Do I need to have something as `ENTRYPOINT` ?

Comment: You might want to run the container in privileged mode to make it support vagrant or in a way further nesting.